# Embeded youtube video won't play on IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, youtube, embed

I have an embeded youtube video, and it won't play on IE in windows 8. It plays in all other browsers in Windows 8 that I can think of, just not IE. It also works on safari on the ipad, and the included browser in android phones and tablets. Does anything see anything not IE compatible in this html?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 
<style type="text/css"> 
*{margin:0;padding:0} html,
 body {height:100%;width:100%;overflow:hidden} 
table {height:100%;width:100%;table-layout:static;border-collapse:collapse} iframe {height:112%;width:100%} 
.header {border-bottom:0px solid #000000} 
.content {height:100%} 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<table> 
<tr><td class="header"><div><h1></h1></div></td></tr> <tr>
<td class="content"> <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VideoAddress?modestbranding=1&autoplay=1&controls=0&iv_load_policy=3&rel=0&showinfo=0&theme=light&color=white&autohide=0&disablekb=1&vq=hd1080" frameborder="0">
</td></tr> 
</table> 
</body> 
</html>
```

(obviously VideoAddress is replaced with the address of the video)

Comment: please specify the version of IE when asking an IE-related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is maybe a IE8 64 bit issue.

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/000/6b3af6c9.html